# Why is php handling for different than foreach?

Tags: php, arrays

I made an array `$brands` inside `class Cars`, the `print_r` output looks like this:

```
Array ( [0] => Array (  [id] => 1 
                        [name] => 'Porsche'
                    ) 
        [1] => Array (  [id] => 2 
                        [name] => 'Bugatti'
                    ) 
        [2] => Array (  [id] => 3 
                        [name] => 'BMW'
                    ) 
    )
```

But when I'd like to link to a certain brand, I don't want to use `strtolower()` to make a lowercased hyperlink. I would like to echo `$cars->brands[$i]['url']` (instead of `strtolower($cars->brands[$i]['name'])`).

---

### class Cars {

So I needed to create a for loop, to create the `['url']` key in the array. I thought that a foreach would work:

```
foreach ($this->brands as $brand => $row) {
    $row['url'] = strtolower($row['name']);
}
```

But it didn't. Even this did not work: `$row['name'] = strtolower($row['name']);`.

---

But this worked, though:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->brands); $i++) { 
    $this->brands[$i]['url'] = strtolower($this->brands[$i]['name']);
}
```

### }

---

My question here is: how? why?

Comment: That's because in your `foreach`-loop, `$row` is actually a _copy_ of the original while in the `for`-loop, your accessing the actual array.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson has the right of it. `foreach($this->brands as &$row)` would work.

Comment: You can read this post for an in-depth explanation on how `foreach` works: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-does-php-foreach-actually-work

Comment: The concerned concept and solution are also explained in the [docs on `foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want to edit the element being iterated you can add a `&` before $row

```
foreach ($this->brands as $brand => &$row) {
    $row['url'] = strtolower($row['name']);
}
```

but this is not necessary, just access the array from the variable available outside of the foreach loop e.g `$this->brands`

```
foreach ($this->brands as $brand => $row) {
    $this->brands[$brand]['url'] = strtolower($row['name']);
}
```

Comment: So the `&` means you refer to `$this->brand` instead of creating a new variable?

Answer (score 4):

You need to work on a reference. Insert a & and it will work

```
foreach ($this->brands as $brand => &$row) {
    $row['url'] = strtolower($row['name']);
}
```

or you could work on the original array like:

```
foreach ($this->brands as $brand => $row) {
    $this->brands[$brand]['url'] = strtolower($row['name']);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

because you are overwriting array key('url').

**$row** is a local copy of **$this->brands** any changes to **$row** will not reflect on **$this->brands**.

change this

```
foreach ($this->brands as $brand => $row) {
    $row['url'] = strtolower($row['name']);
}
```

with this

```
foreach ($this->brands as $brand => $row) {
    $this->brands[$brand]['url'] = strtolower($row['name']);
}
```

**Happy Coding.**

Comment: There are many ways to solve particular problem.  Thanx for appreciation. Happy Coding.